# Subdominios configurados con Traefik dejan de funcionar al activar la protección de cloudflare

Tags: docker, docker-compose, letsencrypt, traefik2

Tengo configurados y funcionando los subdominios:

> midominio.com, api.midominio.com, proxy.midominio.com

Me estaba dando problemas porque no conseguía hacerlos funcionar, y me he dado cuenta de que solo me funcionaban los subdominios que tenían desactivada la protección de proxy de cloudflare. ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto, o no es posible tener habilitada la protección de cloudflare teniendo un proxy inverso?

Este es el docker-compose:

```yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  main:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    command:
      #- "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--api.debug=true"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      #- "--providers.file.filename=/dynamic.yaml
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik-net"
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=email@mydomain.com"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=acme.json"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnsChallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnsChallenge.provider=cloudflare"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/docker/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    configs:
      - source: config
        target: /dynamic.yaml
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=email@mydomain.com
      - CF_API_KEY=mySecret
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.services.proxy.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
        - "traefik.http.routers.proxy.rule=Host(`proxy.mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.proxy.service=api@internal"
        - "traefik.http.routers.proxy.entrypoints=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.proxy.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.proxy.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
        #- "traefik.http.routers.proxy.middlewares=auth"
        #- "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=user:password/"
networks:
  traefik-net:
    external: true
configs:
  config:
    external: true
    name: traefik-config.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he podido solucionar el problema. Buscando información por los foros de cloudflare, encontré una publicación de una persona a la que las páginas entraban en un bucle de redirección.

Una de las respuestas proponía como solución, habilitar el modo SSL estricto. De esa forma se ha resuelto el problema. Por lo que parece, puede pasar si tienes el modo flexible o completo habilitado (En mi caso, el segundo)

[image: Apartado SSL/TLS de cloudflare]